# My BPEL sends email using multipart/related while I set it to multipart/mixed

Tags: email, mime, bpel, oracle-soa

I'm working on a BPEL project in Oracle 11g SOA suite. I set my BPEL email
notification content type to multipart/mixed but when I get it in my email, the header
shows that it's multipart/related! It causes some issues with my attachment in Lotus notes.
Anyone knows how to force BPEL to send out email with Multipart/mixed content type ?

Answer (score 1):

Download and apply patch 'p13349379_111130_Generic.zip' from Oracle Support Site.